# Regular expression for LaTeX with escaped } (curly brace) needed

Tags: regex, latex, pcre

I just started to write a C program converting some LaTeX into HTML code. The best way in my opinion is to use regular expressions, yet I cannot make this simple idea work with PCRE: Replace something like `\term{abc}` by `[pre]abc[/pre]` (`\term` is a Latex command of my own). Right now here's the catch:

1. How do I handle escaped curly braces (`\}`) in `\term`?
2. How do I handle pairs like `{}`?
3. How do I make the regular expression so greedy that it consumes the first of many `\term` commands, but not all of them?

Well, many questions to figure it out. Hope somebody can help?

PS: I'm sorry if, in any case, I have overlooked an answer to a similar question...

Comment: These are really three separate questions. You will likely get better responses if you break this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See perlfaq6(1) for "Can I use Perl regular expressions to match balanced text?". That said, since latex's complexity seems similar (if not worse) than (x)html, you might want to heed the words of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/) .

Comment: I knew that answer would get a mention. I could smell Cthulu.

Comment: Sigh, I was kinda hoping to avoid writing a "real" LaTeX parser and be able to work with PCRe instead. Seems my gut feeling was right in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you need, but you might consider htlatex (part of TeX4HT), pandoc or any of several other options.  TeX is notoriously hard to parse.